# Trouble Loading External SVG File Using <use> Element in Vite Development Server

Tags: html, svg, vite

I'm having trouble using the `<use>` element in SVG to load an external SVG file located at a Vite hosted URL, during `npm run dev`:

`http://[::1]:5173/resources/img/svg/icons/ico-foodbank.svg#ico-foodbank`.

Here's the code I'm using:

```html
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="http://[::1]:5173/resources/img/svg/icons/ico-foodbank.svg#ico-foodbank"></use>
</svg>
```

When I try to load the SVG file using the `<use>` element, it doesn't display anything.

In fact, it doesn't even load at all:

[image]

I've confirmed that the URL is valid by opening it directly in my browser, and it displays the required SVG image.

For example,
[image]

I can also successfully load the SVG image using the `<img>` element, like this:

```html
<img src="http://[::1]:5173/resources/img/svg/icons/ico-foodbank.svg#ico-foodbank">
```

However, for some reason, it doesn't work when I try to load it using the `<use>` element within an SVG container.

Also, note that the compiled asset Vite URL loads successfully, no problem, e.g.:

```html
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="https://mywebsite.com/build/assets/ico-foodbank-dfc4cd67.svg#ico-foodbank"></use>
</svg>
```

Can anyone help me understand why this might be happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: I am suspecting it has something to do with CORS but I am not sure

Comment: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2015Mar/0139.html